# Repartitioned 1TB APFS SSD to MSDOS 120GB for Linux. Linux installer sees wrong slice names, though cfdisk reports correctly

Tags: partition, unix, apfs, ext4

model: macbook pro (2016) 3.5G Intel
1TB SSD
Ventura 13.5

Attempt 1) Resized a 120GB partition for Ubuntu. Big mistake, lost all data.
Attempt 2) Reinstalled Ventura 13.5, partitioned 120GB for EXT4 but selected msdos.

This worked. Sort of. Ubuntu installer when in manual mode sees the nvme slices, but they are incorrect and very small. Going to terminal and running cfdisk, I saw the correct 120GB, deleted, readded, ran mkfs.ext4, but the Ubuntu installer still sees the wrong nvme slices and wrong sizes (120GB might be 15GB on nvme0n1p2 instead of p3, etc..)

Ugh. I know one way to make it work. But I think I have to blow up the SSD GUID table again :\

Is this a known problem? It seems like others can install Linux, I'd just rather dual boot.